# How to reference a cell by location instead of cell name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hopefully this is a very basic question. There may be a simpler way to solve my problem, so I'll go over that first then ask the question I'm trying to ask.

My problem: I want A1=0 A2=1 A3=2 ... A500=499

My thought is to do something like "=[A:This-1]+1" where This is the number of the cell I'm currently working in. Is there a 'This' variable equivalent? Or some way to say always use the cell above instead of having to go through all 500 cells and count?

Comment: `=ROW(A1)-1` and populate down

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - you can save a byte or two with `=ROW()-1`.  Edit: Or, in `A1`, just enter `0`, then in `A2`, `=A1+1` and drag down.  Or...

Comment: @BruceWayne I could be wrong, but I believe `ROW()` is a volatile function.  Apparently it depends what web page you reads to whether or not ROW() is a volatile function.

Answer (score 1):

To get something similar to `=[A:This-1]+1`, try using `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)+1`

`ROW()` will give you the row number of the cell that the formula is in (15 if the formula is in B15) and subtract 1 (14). [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) will then get the value in A14 and add 1 (25 if the value in A14 is 24).

If you need to also do relative math on the column, you can use the [`ADDRESS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) function like so:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1,4,1)+1
```